# 'IM003', '[IM003] system error 126: The specified module could not be found (When using ICU library)

Tags: visual-c++, odbc, amazon-redshift, pyodbc, icu

Building C/C++ code in `windows` for the first time in my career,

I need to make a change in a 'legacy' ([odbc](https://github.com/aws/amazon-redshift-odbc-driver)) code to use a new ([ICU](https://icu.unicode.org/download/72), static) library.

I made code changes via Vidual studio (2015) and added include and lib dependncies via project properties.

Build (dll) and packaging (msi) is done via a script in command line.

If I build the original code base with no changes, application works as expected.

As soos as I add minimal ICU related stuff, I get an error:

```
#include <unicode/ucnv.h>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/urename.h>
#include <unicode/stringpiece.h>

// Unicode version of SQLExecDirect.
//
SQLRETURN SQL_API SQLExecDirectW(SQLHSTMT   phstmt,
                                    SQLWCHAR* pwCmd,
                                    SQLINTEGER  cchLen)
{
    icu::UnicodeString ustr(pwCmd, cchLen*sizeof(SQLWCHAR));
    //...
}
```

When I test the build using:

```
import pyodbc
query = 'anything'
statement = f"SELECT '{query}'"
print(statement)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver (x64)};Server=xxx;Port=5439;Database=dev;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(statement)
val = cursor.fetchall()[0][0]
```

I get:

```
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
xxx\Documents\test.py in line 9
      10 query = 'anything'
      11 statement = f"SELECT '{query}'"
----> 12 cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver (x64)};Server=xxx;Port=5439;Database=dev;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx')
     13 cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    InterfaceError: ('IM003', '[IM003] Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error  126: 
 The specified module could not be found. 
(Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver (x64), C:\\Program Files\\Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver x64\\Drivers\\rsodbc.dll). 
(160) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

- I do not have this problem in Linux.
- I used `dumpbin` against
  rsodbc.dll and it doesn't seem to contain SQLDriverConnect the way it
  apeared before linking ICU lib(not 100% sure though)

Any hints plz?

Answer (score 0):

Checking my odbc.dll using `Dependencies` app, I realized that, I also needed to include icuuc70.dll & icudt70.dll in the same folder as my odbc.dll. (i had just linked against icu*.lib files)